# Django, exclude() function on list

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

I have a list and I would to remove from it all elements that are contained into an other list.

So, I would to have something like to '`exclude`' queryset but on a list.

Now this is my code:

```
list = Friend.objects.friends(self.request.user)
i_am_blocking = User.objects.filter(blocks_received__user_blocking=self.request.user)
is_blocking_me = User.objects.filter(blocks_set__user_blocked=self.request.user)
            blocked_users = list(chain(i_am_blocking, is_blocking_me))
```

and now I would to remove from '`list`' all items that are contained into '`blocked_users`'.

Is there a better way to make this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the list comprehension:

```
list = [friend for friend in list if friend.user not in blocked_users]
```

**UPDATE**: to do the same at ORM level you can use query like this:

```
list = Friend.objects.friends(self.request.user) \
                     .exclude(user__in=blocked_users)
```

Comment: ok, this work well. Do you think is a good way (efficient) to do this?
Can you see any improvement?

Comment: It depends on amount of firends and blocked users.  You should test it by yourself.  I added the alternative, ORM-based, solution to the answer. It may be more efficient than manipulating data in python.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Is not possible for me use .exclude because Friend.objects.friends(self.request.user) returns a 'list' not a queryset. So, I'll get an error like this: 'list' object has no attribute 'exclude'

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more optimized version:

```
friend_list = Friend.objects.friends(self.request.user)
i_am_blocking = User.objects.filter(...).values_list('pk', flat=True)
is_blocking_me = User.objects.filter(...).values_list('pk', flat=True)
blocked_users = set(chain(i_am_blocking, is_blocking_me))

friend_list = [friend for friend in friend_list if friend.user_id not in blocked_users]
```

This has two main advantages. First, `blocked_users` is a `set`, so `user not in blocked_users` doesn't have to loop through all blocked users to determine if the condition is true or not. Secondly, by getting a list of `pk`'s, and comparing to `friend.user_id`, you avoid an extra query for each possible friend: `user_id` is a local field on `friend`, while `user` is an accessor that fetches the whole `user` object from the database.

The most efficient would still be to filter at the ORM level. Btw, please don't assign anything to `list`. It shadows the built-in `list()` type, if necessary you can use `list_`, but it's generally better to use a more descriptive name.